# I have a question about how chefs work at restaurants, not necessarily related to cooking. Is it off topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was wondering if chefs are ever forced to compromise on quality due to time constraints and if there are any tricks they commonly use to speed up the cooking process. Would this fit well into Seasoned Advice? Are there any other sites that would be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: I completely agree with @Jefromi. Questions of this nature could be stellar, but they have to be presented in manageable chunks.

Comment: I'd love to be able to add my 10 cents worth to what is an apposite question on the subject but my gut feeling is that this would be better answered within a forum dedicated to the subject of gastronomy which, to my knowledge, hasn't yet been created on or by stackexchange How would one go about introducing such a forum?

Comment: @Jefromi May I refer you my comment above and invite your suggestion, if any?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you *are* trying to ask about cooking, but it's not a great question yet because it's really broad.

Asking how to do any one cooking task faster is a great cooking question, and doesn't just apply to restaurants. Asking about how to plan and organize cooking tasks and fit them all in is also a good cooking question.

(The bit about whether they ever compromise... I suppose it might be okay but seems like the answer is obviously yes, there are always tradeoffs, and so you'll immediately want to ask a more specific question to learn about those tradeoffs and related techniques.)